# How to iterate through a sys_refcursor with unknown type?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Let's define a function

```
create or replace function GET_SOME_CURSOR(X number) return sys_refcursor is
  R sys_refcursor;
begin
  open R for
    select * from MY_TABLE T where T.RATING = X;
  return R;
end;
```

Suppose we don't know what names MY_TABLE columns have (in addition to RATING).
Please, tell me how to solve the following task. Maybe it looks pointless, but I hope your solution
will show me some aspects of PL/SQL I need to know.

Write a function which in cycle (for x = 1 to 10) gets another refcursor from GET_SOME_CURSOR(x) 
and if a column named `TITLE` is NOT present in the refcursor result set then return NULL,
otherwise find all rows in the result set, which contain substring 'ABC' in the `TITLE` column and
put into an array (or anyting you want) and return this array.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Unless you're using new 12c features, getting metadata about the cursor is going to be problematic from PL/SQL.

Comment: I use 11g. What do you mean 'problematic' - is it impossible in pl/sql to do simple iteration through data without making declaration of new record type for every case. Do I have to create specific data type every time I want to see what is in my query (without extracting select statement itself out of the function)?

Comment: Generally, the caller needs to know the structure of the result that is going to be returned, yes.  That's going to make the code far cleaner and far more managable.  The set of use cases where code calls a function that returns an unknown result and then behaves differently based on the metadata of the result set is not large.  If that's really what you wanted to do, you'd generally use the `dbms_metadata` package to execute the query rather than getting a `sys_refcursor` from a function.

Comment: Thank you, @JustinCave. I just couldn't belive that all in pl/sql is so strict, but let it be.

Answer (score 4):

This one should provide desired information

```
DECLARE
    r SYS_REFCURSOR;

    cur INTEGER;
    col_tab DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
    col_cnt INTEGER;

BEGIN
    OPEN r FOR 
    select * from MY_TABLE T where T.RATING = X;

    cur := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(rc);
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(cur, col_cnt, col_tab);
    FOR i IN 1..col_cnt LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column '||i||': '||col_tab(i).col_name 
            ||' Data type is: '||col_tab(i).col_type );
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE r;
END;
```

Translation from `col_type` number to readable data type string you get by this query:

```
SELECT text
FROM all_source
WHERE owner = 'SYS' 
    AND NAME = 'DBMS_TYPES' 
    AND TYPE = 'PACKAGE' 
    AND REGEXP_LIKE(text, 'TYPECODE');
```

Comment: This is a great resource. Did not realize the source code was staring me in the face in that table all this time.