# Pass SELECT STATEMENT as IN parameter to procedure and execute in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, parameters, procedure

I have following procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_create_text_file (
   loc IN VARCHAR2
   , file IN VARCHAR2
   , select_statement in varchar2
   , line_statement in varchar2
)
IS
    fid UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN (loc, file, 'W');
    line VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        /*replace this select*/
        select
        parameter
        , value
        from nls_database_parameters
        where parameter in ('NLS_RDBMS_VERSION', 'NLS_CHARACTERSET')
        /*end of replace*/
    )
    LOOP
        line := rec.parameter || ';' || rec.value;
        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (fid, line);
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fid);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fid);
END;
/
```

and I need to replace the select statement with "something" so that it can be passed in an IN parameter SELECT_STATEMENT.

The procedure call should look like this:

```
begin
    p_create_text_file (
       loc => 'EXPDIR'
       , file => 'exp.log'
       , select_statement => 'select parameter, value from nls_database_parameters where parameter in (''NLS_RDBMS_VERSION'', ''NLS_CHARACTERSET'')'
       , line_statement => null
    );
end;
/
```

I tried dynamic SQL but it did not work.

The procedure should be able to process any select statement.

Comment: your problem is when you call the procedure ? your having error in the `select_statement` , then you want to execute this select in the procedure ??

Comment: No, there is a compilation error. I can't just replace the select statement inside the loop with "execute immediate select_statement".

Comment: you want to replace the select in the for loop with a variable right ?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass the select statement to the procedure in a in parameter select_statement.

Comment: It looks like you want to output the results of any query to a semicolon-serperated file, right? If it has to process any select statement (ignoring how you validate that what you've been passed is just a query, not something nasty), how do you plan do anything with the data inside the loop - since you won't know at compile time what columns will be in the result set?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use external table over `UTL_FILE` because you already have a directory available. Either way, things get complicated if you want a dynamic SQL statement without knowing in advance what the columns / datatypes are going to be passed within the `select`, as Alex said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you don't know the columns that wil be returned by the passed-in query at compile time, you can't refer to them inside the loop statically.

You could use the `dbms_sql` package to do this dynamically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_create_text_file (
   loc IN VARCHAR2
   , file IN VARCHAR2
   , select_statement in varchar2
   , line_statement in varchar2 -- not used?
)
IS
   fid UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN (loc, file, 'W');

   -- for dbms_sql
   l_c pls_integer;
   l_col_cnt pls_integer;
   l_desc_t dbms_sql.desc_tab3;
   l_rc pls_integer;
   l_varchar varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
   -- create cursor and prepare from passed-in statement
   l_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
   dbms_sql.parse(c=>l_c, statement=>select_statement,
      language_flag=>dbms_sql.native);
   dbms_sql.describe_columns3(c => l_c, col_cnt => l_col_cnt,
      desc_t => l_desc_t);

   -- define all columns as strings; this will end up with implicit conversion
   -- of dates etc. using NLS settings, so shoudl be finsessed based on data
   -- actual data type really...
   for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
      dbms_sql.define_column(c=>l_c, position=>i,
         column=>l_varchar, column_size=>4000);
   end loop;

   -- execute the query
   l_rc := dbms_sql.execute(c=>l_c);

   -- fetch each row in turn
   while dbms_sql.fetch_rows(c=>l_c) > 0 loop
      -- for each column from describe
      for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
         -- get the column value for this row (again, as string...)
         dbms_sql.column_value(l_c, i, l_varchar);
         -- write out to file, with delimiter after first column
         if i > 1 then
            UTL_FILE.PUT (fid, ';');
         end if;
         UTL_FILE.PUT (fid, l_varchar);
      end loop;
      UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE (fid);
   end loop;

   dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_c);

   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fid);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fid);
END;
/
```

That, bascally, parses the passed-in statement, executes it, fetches each row, gets each column value in turn (as a string, which could/should be expanded to avoid implicit conversions), and writes ach of those out to the file in turn - adding a delimiter between them, and a final new-line after each row.

When called from your anonymous block that creates a file containing:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET;AL32UTF8
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION;11.2.0.4.0
```

Be aware, thoguh, that this will run anythign it's given, including DDL (which is executed when parsed). If you don't control how this is called, and really even if you do, you should add validation of the passed-in statement to verify that is is actually just a query.

You might find it simpler to explore other methods, such as external tables (as @Kaushik suggested), or client functionality.

---

As @kfinity suggested in a comment, you could use a ref cursor to parse and execute the query, which should prevent anything nasty from being run. The `dbms_sql` package [has a function to convert a ref cursor to a native cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-C105E213-D766-4221-BE1B-62736AE8FB8D), so using that insetad of the explicit open, parse and execute steps:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_create_text_file (
   loc IN VARCHAR2
   , file IN VARCHAR2
   , select_statement in varchar2
   , line_statement in varchar2 -- not used?
)
IS
   fid UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN (loc, file, 'W');

   -- for initial parse and execute
   l_refcursor sys_refcursor;

   -- for dbms_sql
   l_c pls_integer;
   l_col_cnt pls_integer;
   l_desc_t dbms_sql.desc_tab3;
   l_rc pls_integer;
   l_varchar varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
   -- open ref cursor for the statement
   open l_refcursor for select_statement;

   -- convert ref cursor to dbms_sql cursor
   l_c := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(l_refcursor);
   dbms_sql.describe_columns3(c => l_c, col_cnt => l_col_cnt,
      desc_t => l_desc_t);

   -- define all columns as strings; this will end up with implicit conversion
   -- of dates etc. using NLS settings, so shoudl be finsessed based on data
   -- actual data type really...
   for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
      dbms_sql.define_column(c=>l_c, position=>i,
         column=>l_varchar, column_size=>4000);
   end loop;

   -- fetch each row in turn
   while dbms_sql.fetch_rows(c=>l_c) > 0 loop
      -- for each column from describe
      for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
         -- get the column value for this row (again, as string...)
         dbms_sql.column_value(l_c, i, l_varchar);
         -- write out to file, with delimiter after first column
         if i > 1 then
            UTL_FILE.PUT (fid, ';');
         end if;
         UTL_FILE.PUT (fid, l_varchar);
      end loop;
      UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE (fid);
   end loop;

   dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_c);

   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fid);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fid);
END;
/
```

... which produces the same output file.

---

Incidentally, if you wanted to you could also write the column names out as a header row, before the fetch-rows loop:

```
   -- write column names as header row
   for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
      if i > 1 then
         UTL_FILE.PUT (fid, ';');
      end if;
      UTL_FILE.PUT (fid, l_desc_t(i).col_name);
   end loop;
   UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE (fid);
```

Comment: Do you think using a refcursor would help with the issue of executing non-select statements? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27229320/3061852

Comment: @kfinity - yes, that's a good idea; opening the refcursor would fail for a non-query, and you'd then convert it. Nice.