# BULK COLLECT INTO dynamic number of columns with multiple rows

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, plsql

I am trying to store the results of a dynamic query that returns multiple rows into separate varaibles. These are then being used to populate a CSV file. I have tried  several suggestions but just can't seem to get it to work.

Here is what I've done so far:

Variables declared:

```
TYPE Array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
TYPE ArrayArray IS TABLE OF Array;
```

Code:

```
values ArrayArray();

values.extend(20);

query:= Select ....... (columns from another function, can change)

execute immediate query bulk collect into values(1),values(2),.... (needs to be dynamic)
```

How can I make this work with a variable number of columns in the result set?

Comment: You can't do that; but why do you want to use bulk-collect at all if you're just going to loop over them anyway? You might find [something like this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52971497/266304) useful; you'd just be building the query statement from another query rather than passing it in, if I understand your explanation.

Comment: Are you going to do anything with the selected data other than write it to a CSV file?